# Java ip pinging

Tags: java, ip, ping, host

When I ping addresses in Java I use this code to test if they are reachable

```
    reachable = (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(5000));
```

I get host from database. So my problem is, I need to fill my ProgressBar by 1 each time one ip address is pinged, but its kinda problem cause this line pings all Ip addresses and only then it displays results.So there is no point of progress bar if its full when pinging is done.

Comment: is this a desktop/web app? Not really sure what is the question

Comment: This line pings one address only. Once `isReachable()` returns you can update your process bar.

Comment: @AlexR sorry I'am kinda new to this,could you explain where exactly I have to put command, is it in this code? And is it possible to ping more than one Ip address at time?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [InetAddress.getAllByName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName%28java.lang.String%29) to get all ip addresses for that host, and then use isReachable() on each IP address in turn ?

```
foreach(InetAddress ia : InetAddress.getAllByName(host)) {
   if (ia.isReachable(5000)) {...

}
```